# Getting Office 365 Outlook User Photo through REST

Tags: api, rest, outlook, office365

I'm currently able to view the photo metadata using :

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo
```

and i'm able to get a correct response like this :

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/photo/$entity",
"@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-7d04-b48b-20075df800e5@1717622f-1d94-c0d4-9d74-f907ad6677b4')/photo",
"@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
"@odata.mediaEtag": "\"BA09D118\"",
"Id": "240X240",
"Width": 240,
"Height": 240
}
```

However I get NULL when I try to query :

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo/$value
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the reason why it does not work with the alias "me" but if you use the *@odata.id* and request the value with the following request

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-7d04-b48b-20075df800e5@1717622f-1d94-c0d4-9d74-f907ad6677b4')/photo/$value
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.. I just had to include the content type in the header as:

```
"Content-Type: image/jpg"
```

It works for both 'me' and 'odata id'